# Responding other 'Content-Type' different from 'Accept' list

Tags: http, http-headers, headers, content-type

As all you know ([else follow this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/31231/90137)) the requesting `Accept` header allows client to specify the expected MIME types for response content.

But my case is:

- client indicates an `Accept` of type `image/*`
- server process the request but encounters an error, so it has to return other status code different from `200 OK`, and a JSON with information about error, so `Content-type: application/json` is the response

So I have a few questions:

- Is this case a typical [`406 Not Acceptable` response status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7)?
- Is so ugly to return other `Content-type` not matching the requested `Accept` header?

Also I got to the [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) but I don't see anyway how will solve, because the returned `Content-type` still not matching the requested ones.

Comment: Most URLs only offer a single type of content regardless of the accept request headers.   I'd imagine that if a limited accept is sent, it isn't honored by most servers.   On the other hand, most browsers send a star as the last part of the accept (they will accept anything).   Which client is so limited?

Comment: Client is not a browser, but would be REST client developed by others. I don't know how limited can be or auto-magically-rules would apply. I would like also to avoid _force_ the client to add too much code.